# \pagestyle{headings} causing \hbox warning due to long chapter name

Tags: header-footer

I am being prompted with the following error while using `\pagestyle{headings}` on a `book` class LaTeX document:

```
Overfull \hbox (240.44835pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
\OT1/cmr/m/sl/12 CHAPTER 1. THE CITY OF CARTHAGE WAS THE CENTRE OF THE ANCIENT
CARTHAGINIAN CIVILIZATION \OT1/cmr/m/n/12 2
```

The following is the offending code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,oneside]{book}

\pagestyle{headings}


\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{The city of Carthage was the centre of the ancient Carthaginian civilization}
The city of Carthage was the centre of the ancient Carthaginian civilization. The city developed from a Phoenician colony of the 1st millennium BC into the capital of an ancient empire.[2] The area of Carthage was before inhabited by Berber people who also became the bulk of Carthage's population and constituted a significant part of its army, economy and administration. Native Berbers and settling Phoenicians in Carthage mixed in different ways including religion and language, creating the Punic language and culture.

The name of Carthage, Latin: Carthago or Karthago,  meaning "New City" 

The first civilization that developed within the city's sphere of influence is referred to as Punic (a form of the word "Phoenician") or Carthaginian. The city of Carthage is located on the eastern side of Lake Tunis across from the centre of Tunis. According to Greek historians, Carthage was founded by Canaanite-speaking Phoenician colonists from Tyre (in modern Lebanon) under the leadership of Queen Elissa or Dido. It became a large and rich city and thus a major power in the Mediterranean. The resulting rivalry with Syracuse, Numidia, and Rome was accompanied by several wars with respective invasions of each other's homeland.

Hannibal's invasion of Italy in the Second Punic War culminated in the Carthaginian victory at Cannae and led to a serious threat to the continuation of Roman rule over Italy; however, the Romans gained the upper hand by invading Africa and defeating Carthage at the Battle of Zama in 202 BC. Following the Third Punic War, the city was destroyed by the Romans in 146 BC. However, the Romans refounded Carthage, which became the empire's fourth most important city and the second most important city in the Latin West. It later became the capital of the short-lived Vandal kingdom. It remained one of the most important Roman cities until the Muslim conquest, when it was destroyed a second time in 698.

The ancient Greek philosopher Aristotle wrote extensively on Carthaginian politics, and he considered the city to have one of the best governing institutions in the world, along with those of the Greek states of Sparta and Crete.[5][6]

\section{Topography}
Carthage was built on a promontory with sea inlets to the north and the south. The city's location made it master of the Mediterranean's maritime trade. All ships crossing the sea had to pass between Sicily and the coast of Tunisia, where Carthage was built, affording it great power and influence.

\end{document}
```

The `\hbox` refers to:

[image: heading too wide]

[image: long chapter name]

How can I solve this issue using `\pagestyle{myheadings}`? Or how can I solve this issue keeping the book class heading format?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: btw, you should let LaTeX properly hyphenate the words by adding `\hyphenation{Car-tha-gi-nian Car-tha-go}` in the preamble.

Comment: @Sveinung My comment was not to heading, but to the whole document. English hyphenation patterns don't hyphenate either of the two words, which is wrong. Alternative is to use `\foreignlanguage{latin}{...}` but that's an overkill.

Answer (score 4):

It is not a good idea to have long headers. You can use the optional argument of `\chapter` macro.

```
 \chapter[optional]{mandatory}
```

The `optional` is used for running content like toc and headers,

```
\chapter[The city of Carthage]{The city of Carthage was the centre of the ancient Carthaginian civilization}
```

gives

[image]

Further, it is always better to use `microtype` package (`\usepackage{microtype}`) so that the spacings improve a lot.